# C#: How to Bind Button.Enabled to Whether If There Is Any Item Selected of a ListView

Tags: c#, data-binding, controls, properties

I have a question about Control.DataBindings.

How can I bind Button.Enabled to whether if there is any item selected of a ListView? i.e.:

```
Button.Enabled = ListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0;
```

I know that I can use ListView.SelectionChanged event to do this.

I'm just wondering how can I use DataBinding to do the same job.

Thanks.

Peter

P.S.: The reason I want to do this is: if Button.Enabled is depending on the conditions of a lot of other controls, I think DataBinding is simpler.

Comment: What would you bind it to? I would use the SelectionChanged event like you suggested.

Comment: If only it were WPF/Silverlight, it would be sooo easy...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use bindings, you'd need to create a ValueConverter. This is done by implementing the [System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) interface (the MSDN page has an example implementation). In it you would return true if the `int` passed in is greater than 0.

In your case, you would bind `Button.Enabled` to `ListView.SelectedItems.Count`, and specify your value converter.

As @PaulG said in the comments, it is possibly easier to just use the `SelectionChanged` event, but it is possible to do via bindings.

Answer (score 0):

I usually try triggers first then value converters.
You don't actually have to implement a value converter in this case, a simple DataTriggger will do:

```
<Button>
  <Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Enabled When Selection Changed"/>          
      </Style.Setters>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=_listBox, Path=SelectedItems.Count}"
                     Value="0">
          <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Button.Style>
</Button>
<ListBox x:Name="_listBox">
  <ListBox.Items>
    <ListBoxItem Content="1"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="2"/>
  </ListBox.Items>
</ListBox>
```